# Python error from rounding float value of fraction

Tags: python

I am attempting project Euler question #214 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=214) and after a while playing with things I have the functionality working but unfortunately, due to the error where fractions can not be represented exactly, the program outputs some incorrect responses.

The task is essentially to use Euler's totient function (`phi`), which determines the number of co-primes of a number, `k`, from `1` to `k` inclusive. Find `phi(x)`, then `x = phi(x)` and so on until `x = 1`, forming a chain, and find the sum of all primes less than 40 million which form a chain of length 25.

The method of finding phi I have chosen involves multiplying a number, `k`, by `1 - 1/p` for each of its prime factors (represented by `p`). Unfortunately, with certain values such as `3322`, the correct `phi` value is `1500`, but due to pythons storage of primes, the total rounds to `1499` instead. As the numbers grow, the disparity between the correct and outputted answer also grows.

I have tried using Decimal to give a more accurate value but this hasn't worked.

Any advice is appreciated,

```py
def phi(n, phi_values):
    if n in phi_values:
        return phi_values[n]
    else:
        if test_prime(n):
            phi_values[n] = n - 1
            return n - 1
        else:
            factors = prime_factors(n)
            val = int(n * reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), factors))
            phi_values[n] = val
            return val

def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            hold = Decimal(1 - (1 / i))
            if not hold in factors: factors.append(hold)
    if n > 1:
        hold = Decimal(1 - (1 / n))
        if not hold in factors: factors.append(hold)
    return factors
```

Comment: `Decimal(1 - (1 / i))` makes a decimal out of a float (which has already lost precision). You need to actually do arithmetic on decimals, but that probably won't help. Decimals don't magically provide perfect precision, they're just *decimal* instead of normal binary floating point numbers. For example, `1 / 3` does not have an exact decimal representation no matter what you do.
I think some rounding might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I can't just comment, it might help to use this function `float.as_integer_ratio()`, it should reduce the rounding error, if you know what kind of precision you want you could also use `math.isclose()` and give a rounded number yourself.